# GTM Tag not getting fire - Link Click Event

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am novice in GTM. I created 2 tags : Link Click Listeners , Outbound Links. And has rule Outbound Link tagged in Link Click Listeners. My event is not getting fire. Here is the screenshot. Under Firing Rules :
[image]

On the same page i have link which redirect me to the other URL for different domain. I wan to analyse the external link stats via google analytics any help

Comment: Do you have a rule for the link click listener to fire on every page? Also what is the regex you are using for the second condition in the screenshot?

Comment: For link click listener there is only rule added Outbound Link where condition defined in screenshot. 2nd condition is this is the URL where my web site hosted e.g. http://127.0.0.1:8502/app/en.html  & when i click on the url then it redirect to other link. I want to track those stats, click on external link.

Comment: You need to create a tag for the link click listener, with a rule for it to fire on all pages.

Comment: I have created a tag which will fire on pageview event for every page, but still no success. Also how can i check the stats of this in google analytics

Answer (score 0):

The gtm.linkClick event will not fire if you have not added a Link Click Listener tag to your container. The Link Click Listener tag is one of the types of tags built-in to Google Tag Manager. This tag should fire on all pages.

[image: Link Click Listener GTM Tag Type]

Comment: Did you give it a rule to fire on all pages?

Comment: Yes, I was making some silly mistake, URL was wrong as you can see in image 127..0.0.1 :(